# How upload and save image using Sails and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, sails.js

I'm working on a project and I'm using a backend sails js, a MongoDB as database and front-end React js.
I have a problem on the upload image.
Here is the code Sails backend and when I test it in PostMan, I got this result ([result test PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5tV5.png)), and the image is not stored in the specified folder but a value containing id and name of file is inserted in MongoDB,

```js
uploadFile: function (req, res) {
   var image= req.file('avatar');
         image.upload({
          adapter: require('skipper-gridfs'),
          uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/name_db.name_collection',
          dirname: '../../assets/images/'
        }, function (err, filesUploaded) {
          if (err){ 
            
            return res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            /*res.negotiate(err);*/res.json(err);
          }
          else{
           
            
           return
           res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); res.ok({
              files: filesUploaded,
              textParams: req.params.all()
            });
          }
          
        });
      },
```

[result test postMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5tV5.png)

And here is the Reactjs front-end code

```
_handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // TODO: do something with -> this.state.file
  fetch('http://localhost:1337/uploadPhoto/logos', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({avatar:this.state.file})
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())     
  .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
}
```

Sails version 0.12,
React version 15.5,
and MongoDB version 3.4.9.

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you providing all required headers in react.js code? In postman there is one header as I can see. Maybe some authorisation

Comment: you can also debug server code https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

Comment: I've already add a header but it didn't work, (the header in postMan :Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded)   The value did not send and there is no error returned

Answer (score 0):

There is no `dirname` parameter for `skipper-gridfs` adapter because the file won't be stored onto the local file system.
Skipper will store the file into the MongoDB database.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, 
so,i remove dirname parameter and it works when i test it with postman, but in react.js code, i don't know where is that wrong

Answer (score 0):

U need to send it as form Data

```
   let formData = new FormData()
            console.log(values);
            
            await formData.append('profile_picture',values.profile_picture.rawFile,values.profile_picture)
            
            
            await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/moderators',{
                body:formData,
                method:'POST',
                credentials:'include' //If Using Session for react-app instead of JWT token
            })
```